# I am using Navigate to go to another page on React Native, I've tried with navigation & React Dom

Tags: react-native

I am using Navigate to go to another page on React Native, I've tried with navigation & react Dom. I want to go to Home.js. I've tried using NavigationContainer, & reateStackNavigator and also React Dom.

I can't seem to find a solution to either of the two and the YouTube videos aren't really helping.

```
import {
  StyleSheet, 

  Text, 
  SafeAreaView, 
  Image,

  View,
  TouchableOpacity,

} from 'react-native';
import React,{ useState} from 'react';
import {Card} from 'react-native-shadow-cards';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';


import {Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Link, Navigate, NavigationType} from 'react-router-dom';


export default function App() {

  const handlePress = () =>  navigation.navigate('Home');
  const [name,setName] = useState("");
  const shadowstyle={
    shadowOpacity:1
  };
  

  
  return ( 
    
  
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  

    <Image 
    
    source={require("/Users/travisnunnally/Malik Projects VSCODE/Gtipz/assets/Star.png")} />


    <Image 
    source={require("/Users/travisnunnally/Malik Projects VSCODE/Gtipz/assets/Star.png")} />



  <Text style={styles.titleText} onPress={handlePress}>GTipz </Text>


  <Image 
    source={require("/Users/travisnunnally/Malik Projects VSCODE/Gtipz/assets/GtipzLogo.png")} />
   
   <View>
    <Image 
    source={require("/Users/travisnunnally/Malik Projects VSCODE/Gtipz/assets/Star.png")} />
</View>

   <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress}>
<View style ={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.userImageWrapper]}>
 
<Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the useNavigation hook from react-navigation.

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

const navigation = useNavigation()
```

I also suggest you replace Text with TouchableOpacity where you call the `handlePress` function

Please refer to this [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) for more information.